# Duplicate select values in handlbars and nodejs when updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

I was encountering an issue for the last 2 days which duplicating same values when updating drop down select values in hbs using nodes and MongoDB the way i want is when i select a row and i want to update it if there is a same field value for the field i am updating it should return only the one i selected and remove it or override the same value in the select drop down

Here is the picture there are same values wartanabadda:

[image]

Comment: You need to show code so that someone can see where the problem is. As it is, we just have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I got an other way to solve my problem which is replacing hbs to ejs as templating engine and i did all my needs thank you